# How to play audio file in php?

Tags: php

I want to play an MP3 file in using a PHP script. Where to store the audio file and how to give the path in PHP?

Comment: Audio is played in the client's browser. Use javascript and the `audio` element.

Comment: how to integrate in php, pls give me any code snippets

Comment: @Vicky, what have you already tried? Please remember that SO is for programming questions, not solutions!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't do this directly in PHP. You'll have to use HTML5 audio or Flash.

Comment: i am web service for android,i want to fetch mp3 songs from server,so how can i do this scenario

Comment: Without seeing your database and directory structure, it's difficult to help any further I'm afraid!

Comment: I think you need to research this yourself further, Vicky.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side programming language. You can use it to move the file's information and contents, such as via a form upload, to your server, but playing the audio is a client-side concern.

Answer (score 1):

You need to play the mp3 clientside, either with javascript or to embed it with `<embed src="file.mp3">`
You can store the filepath as a variable in PHP with

```
$soundfile = "file.mp3";
```

and then spit out some markup

```
echo "<embed src =\"$soundfile\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
```

Tho, im not sure you can play the .mp3 fileformat using embed. Wav should be fine.

Comment: am also try this but not work,in this code "file.mp3" where it is located

Comment: it would be located in the same folder as the .php script

Answer (score 0):

use this:

[jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-constructor)

or

[soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

this are both javascript and html5 based. though, you can control its playlist using php, depending on how you implement it.