# Play audio file according to a number

Tags: php, mysql, audio, mp3

I am doing a queue system using PHP, kind of you take a ticket and wait for counter to call your number. I have several audio files that recorded the numbers from 0-9.

I want to know how can I play these files according to current number. Ex. if current number is 1005, it will play the '1' audio files first, then play '0' twice, and lastly play '5'.

Please give me some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: use `substr` to get each number...this might be a problem though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950330/how-to-play-audio-file-in-php

Comment: @ewizard exactly what might be the problem? I also think of using explode...guess substr and explode can be the solution. Just want to look for better options if any

Comment: the answer to that question is that you need to play audio files from html...you can't do it with php.